# Sauce Labs alternative

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, automated-tests

We're looking into automating our web UI using either Microsoft's coded UI tests or Telerik TestStudio framework. I would love to run our tests using a service like Sauce Labs however, Sauce Labs requires Selenium tests. Is anyone aware of some service similar to Sauce Labs to run web tests other than Selenium?

Comment: I am presuming you want functional testing? See www.utest.com. By the way, why don't you want to use Selenium?

Comment: You'll probably have to build the test framework yourself on top of existing cloud infrastructure like Amazon EC2 or more likely for your case MS Windows Azure.

Comment: @tebel - I don't want to use selenium because we're hoping to use the Visual Studio testing tools to write web tests.  Selenium is great but there are company policies that prevent us from using it.

Comment: @David - thanks but we're not ready to invest in what it would take to write and support a tool that would run our tests accross multiple versions of multiple browsers on demand.  That would be a pretty big effort.

Comment: @Buzzer, your question would be a perfect opportunity for any entrepreneur to develop a SauceLabs equivalent for MS solution, hopefully someone will come to do that some day. TFS cloud could use a competitor anyways.

Comment: @Buzzer, if the only reason not to use Selenium is because of use of Visual Studio, then that isn't much of a hindrance since Selenium, particularly Selenium 2 / WebDriver has .NET bindings that you can use and run with Visual Studio/MSUnit, though the open source community probably prefers NUnit. Unless you're company has policies against Selenium for open source/IP/proprietary info concerns.

Answer (score 2):

TFS in the cloud looks promising http://tfspreview.com/

Regardless of TFS service or Sauce Lab, be aware that a service only frees you the burden of maintaining a CI/Test server in house. It doesn't magically generate tests for you.  It's still your responsibility to design and code many tests.   That is where huge effort and learning curve will take place.

(Speaking of learning curve, Selenium is much more manageable than Ms coded ui test. Wait for chances to influence company decision...)

Comment: Interesting service. Either I missed the relevant info on the site, or perhaps I'm not familiar not having worked in the full MS ecosystem of code, build, test w/in MS framework, but this service at least from the site docs, is vague on how you can farm out automated UI tests to the cloud. It currently appears more of checkin/out code through cloud, build in cloud, collaborate in cloud and run unit tests in cloud. Not much mention about UI testing in the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Sauce Labs in fact is able to run other (Non-Selenium & Appium) frameworks. There is a testrunner that is super easy to use called saucectl. You can test with CYpress, Test Cafe, Espresso, XCUITest and more. [You can see the info in the docs.](https://docs.saucelabs.com/testrunner-toolkit/)

TLDR

- Install saucectl in your project with cURL or `npm install -g saucectl`
- Setup the runner in your test project with `saucectl init`. choose your framework flavor and preferences
- Run your tests with the
  command `saucectl run`

Answer (score 0):

TFS is not an alternative to Sauce. In fact their is now an integration to run Sauce test from Visual Studio Online formerly TFS. Sauce is a testing grid. The closest competitive solution is BrowserStack. But they are not as widely adopted. But it also is selenium based. Telerik TestStudio is nice, but it also is not the cloud you run on. Maintaining your own grid is a huge part of the value of a cloud-based solution. And selenium really is the best and most supported language for doing it.